# Plot points on image from coordinates python

Tags: python, image, coordinates

I have a .csv file containing coordinates, and I need to plot them usign python on a map I have done. Someone can help me with that?

EDIT: my .csv contains a column of x coordinates and a column of y coordinates, with `;` as delimiter

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x_coords, y_coords)`?

Comment: I need to plot them on a map I have already done, it is not enough to plot them using the `plot` function

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your csv looks its a bit difficult to know. Assuming it's just x,y:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',') 
plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: It is not enough to simply plot the data, I need to plot them on an image as background. Is there a way I can do it?